# Magento2 remove maintanace.html and maintenance.php from pub

Tags: magento2, error, 404, maintenance

I have Magento 2.3.1 instance and it is working perfectly for all inner pages instead of the home page.

when I trying to **access the website with URL** it is **showing the maintenance page**. **but when I access my website followed by index.php it is working correctly**.

In **pub** folder there are two files available **"maintenance.html"** and **"maintenance.php"**. **I tried with deleting both files** it is showing now "**404 not found**" for the home page only. other pages working perfectly.

How can I solve this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Below command to remove the var/.maintenance.flag file:
bin/magento maintenance:disable

Comment: I already disabled the maintenance mode. and no var/.maintenance.flag file available @Sudhanshu Bajaj